# laravel resource route not generating named routes

Tags: routes, laravel-5

So I just created a resource route as follow:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'control-panel'], function () {
   Route::resource('changelog', 'admin\ChangelogController');
});
```

Yet when I try and use any named route in blade it says that the route does not exits. Note that I do have a grouped - prefix route around it.

```
{{ route('changelog.create') }}
```

I really rather not write all routes seperate as I've done now for a quick fix.
I use Laravel 5.2.

Comment: did you create the controller action yet?

Comment: Next that the controller does exists, isnt the cause of the error that the route does not exist. It would show that the controller / method doesnt exist. But yeah, it does. The controller was made with the php artisan make:controller command. When I write out the URL's myself and add a named route it does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using route prefix so the route name will have that prefix too. This must be working:

```
{{ route('control-panel.changelog.create') }}
```

you can override these names by passing a names array with your options:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'control-panel'], function () {

   Route::resource('changelog', 'admin\ChangelogController', ['names' => [
        'create' => 'changelog.create'
    ]]);

});
```

Comment: I will check that as soon as I am home again, but it seems to make sense now that you've mentioned it. Though I am wondering, would there be some way to over-write this aswell? And still be able to just use changelog.create for that matter?

Comment: hmm.. you can see the updated answer. However, I think this is too much coding for not much of benefit. You could just add each route yourself instead of using resources

Comment: It worked but as you said, it might be a little too much coding for the result. Still thinking which I would use but many thanks for this answer!